# Python Seaborn: Keeping X axis constant in Boxplot

Tags: python, seaborn, boxplot

I have a starting point (prod1) and ending point (prod2) and they can be from [A,B,C,D].

I would like to see 4 rows of 4 boxplots, in which the first row is "From A" the boxplot to B, to C, and to D.

Since there is no A to A, B to B, C to C or D to D, the boxplots end up being 3 plots wide.

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    import seaborn as sns
    %matplotlib inline

    cross=np.random.randn(1000)
    prod1 = ['A','B','C','D'] * 250
    prod2 = ['A'] * 250 + ['B'] * 250 + ['C'] * 250 + ['D'] * 250 

df_cross = pd.DataFrame(
    {'prod1': prod1,
     'prod2': prod2,
     'cross': cross
    })
df_cross=df_cross[df_cross['prod1']!=df_cross['prod2']] ##cannot sell to another

    fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4) = plt.subplots(nrows=4, sharey=True)
    fig.set_size_inches(12, 16)


    sns.boxplot(data=df_cross[df_cross['prod1']=='A'], x='prod2', y='cross', ax=ax1)
    sns.boxplot(data=df_cross[df_cross['prod1']=='B'], x='prod2', y='cross', ax=ax2)
    sns.boxplot(data=df_cross[df_cross['prod1']=='C'], x='prod2', y='cross', ax=ax3)
    sns.boxplot(data=df_cross[df_cross['prod1']=='D'], x='prod2', y='cross', ax=ax4)
```

As you can see, the x axis changes with each row. How do I make sure the x axis has A, B, C, D  ?

Comment: Putting more than one question in a question may at the end prevent you from getting any answer at all.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I have modified.